# Displaying the result of a promise in React right away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to display a value from a promise right after mounting/while mounting, but having some issues. In particular, I'm trying to change the state of a component using a promise. Here was my initial try:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    version: -1
  }

  fetchModel('http://localhost:3000/test/info')
    .then(result => this.setState({version: result.__v}));
}
```

This gave me the behavior I wanted, letting me get and display the version in the component, but I got the warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component". I updated it to this after seeing suggestions online:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    version: -1
  }

  this.mounted = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;

  fetchModel('http://localhost:3000/test/info')
    .then(function(result) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        this.setState({version: result.__v})
      }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.mounted = false;
}
```

but it no longer displays the correct version number. Inside the promise, after this.setState, I tried console.log(this.state.version), which did not print anything to the console, and a random console.log statement right afterwards did not print either. Is there anything I can do to get around this issue? Are there better ways to display information from a promise while mounting?

Comment: you need to use [Abortcontroller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController#examples)

Comment: "*it no longer displays the correct version number*" - what else does it display? What debugging did you do? Does the `then` callback still get executed?

Comment: "*I got the warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"*"  - in most cases you can safely ignore that. However you might want to have a look again at how your component is mounted and unmounted. Can you show the code where you're using it?

Comment: perhaps `.then(function(result) {` needs to be an arrow function like it is in the first code

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! @JaromandaX making it an arrow function worked! Can you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?